# Kentico 9 tild not being resolved for files

Tags: kentico

I have a custom page Type that lets the user select uploaded files (pdf, docx, xlxs). I've noticed that the tilde (~) is not being resolved when i look at the rendered page. I've checked the Output Filter in settings, but the settings here are default. What am I missing?

Here's a snippet from my transformation

```
<%# IfEmpty(Eval("File"),"n/a","<a href=" + Eval("File") +" target='blank'><span class='fa fa-download'></span></a>")%>
```

Comment: What is the result? If the website is directly at the root of a domain, ~/ or / will both resolve to something like domain.com/file.pdf, unless your site is running as a application domain.com/myapp, then the ~ would make a difference.

Comment: When I look at the URL for the file i'm seeing the ~ in the URL. so something lie site.com/folder/~/folder/file.aspx.

Comment: Does it happen to all images you insert from media library? Can you try to create a page with editable region, and insert an image directly to the page?

Comment: I've updated the question to a bit. I've also added a snippet from the transformation I have created. It's not images I am seeing this with, but when a pdf, or xlsx file is uploaded to the CMS desk. I'm going to look at the pages Riu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try what's described in this post?
https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/tilde-being-added-to-src-attribute-of-image-tags-in-static-html-webpart

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved this. In my custom page, I have a File Field, which is using the URL selector form control. With the Control Settings, I unchecked Use Relative URL. It seems to be working.